# How to separate web API from IdentityServer created in VS Studio (hosted Blazor WASM with Identity template) as its own project?

Tags: identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

(I try to learn web development)

When creating a hosted Blazor WASM from template we get a server and a client using IdS and Identity. How do we add a new web API project (because of separation of concerns?) and protect it via this template setup?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you currently have 2 apps - an *Identity Server* and a *Blazor app* -, and that you want to create a 3rd app: an *API* that can be consumed by the *Blazor app*, right?

If so, then you are probably already using authentication in your *Blazor app*, with the *Identity Server*. What you will need to do is to take the JWT that you probably have and to pass it to the new *API*, which must also be registered in the *Identity Server*.

The IdentityServer4 GitHub has many samples [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples). I believe that the quickstart for [AspNetCoreAndApis](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis) may be useful for you:

- It is an MVC app that authenticates with [Authorization Code flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow). Then, this MVC app consumes an API protected with JWT authentication :)